# Ajax+eval more harmful than script tag?

Tags: javascript, eval

I am building an application where I load scripts on the go:

```
var newScript=document.createElement("script");
newScript.src="script.js";
document.head.appendChild(newScript);
```

The scripts are in the same domain, so rather than using a script tag I am considering using ajax+eval as it gives me more flexibility (in particular to synchronize with other scripts). Are both options equivalent, or is there any additional risk when using eval?

Comment: I see no `eval`, hear no `eval`.

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question. It has received an answer within minutes, without any "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to risk, both are equivalent.

Both methods execute the downloaded script blindly (without checking). The only difference is that you can't execute script from other domains with ajax.

On the other hand, by downloading the script as text before evaling it you have the chance to run some text processing on it such as checking for known malicious attacks, linting it etc. So you could, in theory, build a secure and/or restricted execution environment by using ajax+eval. But figuring out what is malicious and what is benign is not easy.

Comment: thx! Do you happen to know if jQuery getScript does any such text processing?

Comment: @Christophe: Don't know much about jQuery internals I'm afraid but my guess would be no. Some early JSON parsers used the validate-then-eval technique because it is often faster than parsing the text manually for large objects. Some JSON parsers still fall back to validate-then-eval when native JSON methods/functions are not available.

Answer (score 0):

One of the only legit uses for `eval` is when your AJAX call is returning JavaScript.  While this does give additional flexibility.  I'm not sure about your particular app, but these are the main concerns:

- Users can send any data they want through AJAX.  Make sure your server-side code is clean.
- AJAXing scripts means that the browser can't cache them.  This'll result in a slower user experience.

Comment: `the code you've given won't actually work` the code works fine. It's a standard way to include other javascript files using javascript.

Comment: @SomeKittens thx for the answer. I am definitely talking about getting the script.js file via ajax. There are several points I don't quite understand: 1/ my code above should run the script 2/ AJAXing scripts should still allow caching. 3/ I agree that users can send any data they want through AJAX, but isn't it true of files in script tags too? (I am especially interested in clarifying my point 3/)